# ArgumentOutofRangeException

Tags: c#, exception, arguments

```
Random r = new Random();
        int InvadorNumberA=r.Next(0,5);
        int randomShot = r.Next(5);

        List<Invaders> invadersShooting = new List<Invaders>();
        Invaders invaderA=new Invaders();

        var invaderByLocationX = from invadersSortByLocation in invaders
                                 group invadersSortByLocation by invadersSortByLocation.Location.Y
                                 into invaderGroup
                                 orderby invaderGroup.Key
                                 select invaderGroup;

       invadersShooting = invaderByLocationX.Last().ToList();

     try
       {

           invaderA = invadersShooting[InvadorNumberA];// constantly being thrown there. i cant catch the exception.. so i guess it is being thrown somewhere else. any idea on how i stop it from being thrown?

       }
        catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException dd)
       {
           invaderA = invadersShooting[0];
       }
```

stack Trace

> "   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)\r\n   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)\r\n   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Game.ReturnFire() in D:\Documents and Settings\Dima\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SpaceInvaders\SpaceInvaders\SpaceInvadorGame\Game.cs:line 444"

Target Site

> {Void ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(System.ExceptionArgument, System.ExceptionResource)}

More info:

```
{"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index"}
```

> {"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index"}

i got rid of the exception by simply doing this

```
 invadersShooting = invaderByLocationX.Last().ToList();

           invaderA = invadersShooting[r.Next(0,invadersShooting.Count)];
```

but i am still curious,,on where the exception was thrown..hmmm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't do this.

Exceptions should be *exceptional*. You have every means to prevent this exceptional scenario and you absolutely should.

```
invaderA = invadersShooting[InvadorNumberA];
invaderA = invadersShooting[0];
```

In the first case, `InvadorNumberA` can be anything from 0 to 4. Check and see whether the list has at least `InvadorNumberA + 1` elements in it *before* trying to get an element from it. *Do not* rely upon an exception to correct your course. More than that, perhaps `InvadorNumberA` should actually be constrained to `random.Next(0, list.Count)`. Why create a number from 0 to 4 when there may only be 1 or 2 elements in the list?

Comment: yeah,that was exactly what i changed before looking at your answer. i was surprised to see that try/catch didnt help though..

Comment: With your fix, *you should still check the count*. Your list could be empty. `random.Next(0, 0)` will return 0 (I half expected it to bomb). In an empty list, there will be no element at index 0. Validate!

Answer (score 2):

It could be thrown again in you catch block, as it is not guaranteed that the size of the list is at least 1 there.

Comment: even if i remove all the arguments in the catch block it still throws an exception

Comment: It could be the Enumerable.Last call, but in the documentation it does not say it should throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: @Dmitry, set your IDE to break on all exceptions. (Ctrl+Alt+E should allow you to do so.) Debug the code and see where it's happening and what you're inputs are. The index, the list, it's count, etc.

Comment: Did'nt your development environment tell you where the exception was thrown? if it did please paste the location.

Comment: i added a few details and did what you told me to do

Answer (score 1):

If `invadersShooting` is the empty list you will get an exception thrown in the `try` handler. You will catch this exception in the `catch` handler. However, you then once more index into the empty list and a new exception is thrown, this time in the `catch` handler. That exception is not caught and you have an unhandled exception.

Simply inspect `invadersShooting.Count` before trying to get an element.