# Transferring items from one project to another

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am currently trying to move one project item, a document, from one Project to another using [`IVsProject3::TransferItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsproject3.transferitem?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsProject3_TransferItem_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsWindowFrame_) and [`IVsSupportItemHandoff::HandoffItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssupportitemhandoff.handoffitem?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsSupportItemHandoff_HandoffItem_System_UInt32_Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsProject3_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_VisualStudio_Shell_Interop_IVsWindowFrame_) however both without success.

```cs
IVsProject3Instance.TransferItem(currentPath, newPath, null);
```

In the example above the `currentPath` contains the path of the document which I want to move, and newPath is path which I suspect it to be transferred to. This would be `DirectoryOfTargetProject\\NameOfFileWithExtension` and for the last parameter I passed null, since the doc tells that it is optional.

However both of the methods I try return with the following code:

> -2146233086 which is equal to the `COR_E_ARGUMENTOUTOFRANGE` e.g. `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.
>
> In VisualStudio I get an error message which tells me that the `newPath` (The second parameter I passed) is out of range.

This doesn't make any sense to me since the error itself should't be thrown for a string, at least from my understanding. Is there any reason for this behavior?

Note I am currently using: `Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Preview Version 16.6.0 Preview 2.0`.

Comment: Probably not important, but: why are you still using a preview version?

Comment: @John I am using .Net Core 5 which requires you to use VS 2019 Preview. Additionally I do not really want to install the same VS version twice. See the [VS Support](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/5.0) section.

Comment: Please check [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680525/argumentoutofrangeexception) about the error message.

Comment: @hellogod I am not sure how this is related to my issue, besides that it throws somewhat the same error?

Comment: I suggest you could test it in vs2019 16.5 version. Net Core 5 (preview sdk) is still under testing and maybe there is still a lot of work to do with it.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT This issue is not related to .Net 5 nor to .Net Core at all. Visual Studio Extensions target .Net Framework 4.8